# Why is my calculator program not working? JavaScript and HTML related

Tags: javascript, html

Can anyone help me identify what the problem is in my code?

### HTML

```
  <section>
      <!--- Celsius, Fahrenheit, Kelvin  -->
        <table>

          <tr>
            <td>&#176C</td>
            <td>&#176F</td>
            <td>&#176K</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
              <td><label for="celsius"></label><input type="number" id="celsius"/> </td>
              <td id="fahr1"></td>
              <td id="kelv1"></td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>later</td>
            <td> <input type="number" id="fahrenheit"/> </td>
            <td>later</td>
          </tr>

        </table>
    </section>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
```

and the **JAVASCRIPT** is

```
// Gets Celsius and returns Kelvin
let celsin1 = document.getElementById('celsius');
let fahrout1 = document.getElementById('fahr1');
let kelvout1 = document.getElementById('kelv1');
let newfahr1 = 0;
let newkelv1 = 0;
function celstokelv1(){ newkelv1 = celsin1 + 273;
                            return newkelv1}
function celstofahr1(){newfahr1 = (9/5) * celsin1 + 32;
                            return newfahr1}

function change1() {
    fahrout1.innerHTML = '<td id="fahr1">'+ celstofahr1() +'</td>';
    kelvout1.innerHTML = '<td id="kelv1">' + celstokelv1() + '</td>'
    }

celsin1.addEventListener('change', change1, false);
```

If anyone can help me, it would be much appreciated.

**Problems include:**

When typing into the input bar, the other ones in the same row do not change.

Output for any number into the first Celcius input is **NaN** for Fahrenheit and
**[object HTMLInputElement]273** for Kelvin.

Comment: See Rin Minase's answer for details. You have forgotten to attach the all-important `.value` - what you have done is retrieve a pointer to the input object that you wanted to pull a value from. However, attempting to do maths with that doesn't work and produces the NaN. As a general rule you need to use the value field whenever you are dealing with any type of input-type element (input, button, textarea, select).

Comment: This has already been solved here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57966027/11700321

Comment: Regarding "When typing into the input bar, the other ones in the same row do not change", it is because `change` is only fired after losing focus (which some libraries like jQuery / React will change this behaviour). You may consider using `input` in your `addEventListener`.

Answer (score 2):

Use `.value` to retrieve the value inside your input.
Then use `parseInt()` to convert it into a number to be calculated.

Using the same HTML you created:

```
let celsin1 = document.getElementById('celsius');
let fahrout1 = document.getElementById('fahr1');
let kelvout1 = document.getElementById('kelv1');

let newfahr1 = 0;
let newkelv1 = 0;

function celstokelv1(){ 
    return parseInt(celsin1.value) + 273;
}

function celstofahr1(){
    return (9/5) * parseInt(celsin1.value) + 32;
}

function change1() {
    fahrout1.innerHTML = '<td id="fahr1">'+ celstofahr1() +'</td>';
    kelvout1.innerHTML = '<td id="kelv1">' + celstokelv1() + '</td>'
}

celsin1.addEventListener('change', change1, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`parseInt()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseInt.asp).

```
var val = parseInt(document.getElementById("farenheit").value);
```

It basically converts the string into an integer. Required while doing math to numbers retrieved from elements.

Answer (score 0):

As per your other question.... [Basic Input/Output help for online calculator I am developing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57965843/basic-input-output-help-for-online-calculator-i-am-developing)

**HTML**

```
<section>
   <!--- Celsius, Fahrenheit, Kelvin  -->
   <table>
     <tr>
       <td>&#176C</td>
       <td>&#176F</td>
       <td>&#176K</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td> <input type="number" id="celsius"/> </td>
       <td id="fahr1"></td>
       <td id="kelv1"></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td id="celc2">-</td>
       <td> <input type="number" id="fahrenheit" /> </td>
       <td id="kelv2">-</td>
     </tr>
   </table>
 </section>
```

**JavaScript**

```
const celsius = document.getElementById('celsius');
const fahrenheit = document.getElementById('fahrenheit');

celsius.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
  convertFromCelsius();
});

fahrenheit.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
  convertFromFahrenheit();
});

function convertFromCelsius() {
    var fahr1 = document.getElementById("fahr1");
    var kelv1 = document.getElementById("kelv1");
    fahr1.textContent = parseInt(celsius.value) * (9/5) + 32;
    kelv1.textContent = parseInt(celsius.value) + 273.15;
}

function convertFromFahrenheit() {
    var celc2 = document.getElementById("celc2");
    var kelv2 = document.getElementById("kelv2");
    celc2.textContent = (parseInt(fahrenheit.value) - 32) * (5/9);
    kelv2.textContent = (parseInt(fahrenheit.value) +  459.67) * (5/9);
}
```

**See it working live here:** https://jsfiddle.net/0Luvq4nx/1/